# Shapes, moving, positioning

Tags: css, xhtml

Quick question. I have two rectangles and then text. I want to put the text inside the first rectangle and not the second. When I put e.g. `top:2px;` for the text it will base it off one of the rectangles, but not the one I want. So I want to do it so if you put `2px;` then it will move it 2 pixels from the one I want. Anyone got idea why this is happening? I think it may have something to do with positioning.

Comment: could you make a jsfiddle for it?

Comment: not done css for long don't even know what jsfiddle is, unfortunately =/

Comment: Use this as a starting point: http://jsfiddle.net/En542/ , play with it a bit and then edit your answer, including code samples and the JSFiddle with what you did so far. You might even be able to answer the question yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

Can try this..

```
.rectangle-one{
position:relative;
}
.text{
position:absolute;
top:2px;
}
```